# Memory allocation/release of hostent structure returned by gethostbyname()

Tags: c, memory-management, posix

I have recently been learning socket programming in C and I came across **gethostbyname()** function which returns **struct hostent**. Two of its fields are pointers to an array of pointers terminated by NULL pointer:

```
char** h_addr_list
char** h_aliases
```

I assume that this is dynamically allocated memory and if so then the question emerges - how is that memory released? There is no mention in the documentation about requirement resting on the function caller to release it.

On the other hand **inet_ntoa** returns statically stored char array defined within its body and memory leak is not an issue.

I appreciate your help to understand that memory management kind of topic.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to indicate which OS you are using, either in the text, or tags, or both.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I mean... `gethostbyname()` is POSIX.1-2001. So there isn't a real need to specify the OS, as long as its implementation is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Note that `gethostbyname()` is deprecated and was removed in POSIX-1.2008. You should use `getaddrinfo()`/`freeaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: I believe the [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544411/how-does-gethostbyname-return-struct-hostent-without-requiring-the-caller) will help with your question.  Consider up-clicks if they help.

Comment: @ryyker - thank you, that was very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system, the man page says

```
RETURN VALUE
       The  gethostbyname()  and  gethostbyaddr() functions return the hostent
       structure or a null pointer if an error occurs.  On error, the  h_errno
       variable  holds  an  error number.  When non‐NULL, the return value may
       point at static data, see the notes below.
```

and

```
NOTES
       The  functions  gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() may return pointers
       to static data, which may be overwritten by later calls.   Copying  the
       struct  hostent  does  not  suffice, since it contains pointers; a deep
       copy is required.
```

This phrase `pointer to static data` implies that you should not (nay, *must not*) call `free()` on such pointers.

Comment: I was using man on MacOS which does not state that at all. So it is exactly the same  as in the example with inet_ntoa I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, man pages can vary in quality between platforms.  Normally, I'd recommend going to the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/ig.html) when information is lacking from your manual, but `gethostbyname()` was either never standardised, or removed in favour of the newer reentrant function `getaddrinfo()`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find on older functions that it isn't allocated, nor released, it's stored in a persistent structure that's recycled between calls.

Modern implementations do at least have one of these per thread, though you must be careful when making several calls in sequence as you'll need to extract any data you need before making another call which will invalidate the previous results.